# Nextlink in microsoft graph api is not appearing sometimes

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am making an app that requires a user's email up to a certain date.

For that purpose, I am using Microsoft Graph:

```
/v1.0/users/me/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime+ge+2018-02-04T10:49:38Z
```

It gives 10 emails in one API hit and a `nextlink` for getting the next set.

Sometimes `nextlink` does not appear so my code thinks that there are no more emails left. But when I have checked it, there were emails.

What I want is, to get all the user emails from some date up to today.

Is there any other method to get that because the `nextlink` problem seems always appearing?

Edit 1 :

Even I am trying to do

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$skip=41
```

I am just getting my first 43 emails (I have thousands)

Got to know it is an ongoing issue: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2153

Just thinking, Is there any other reliable source or way ? Any suggestions ??

Comment: The prefered method is using Delta queries (as mentioned in the issue you linked to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delta queries are the only solution I got. So I am implementing like combining all mailfolders of mails which is little tedious task. I hope anyone get help by this.